# ZSH: how to run function with just starting writing parameters frm the list

Tags: zsh

I need to start and stop dockers which have long names. Let us say it is `1.2.3.somelongname-x`, `4.5.6.anotherlongername-y`, `7.8.9-alsolongname-z`. Names were given long to include conf. details. So it is a list of names.

Is there a way to just start typing like `start 1.2` and that proper full name is picked from the list?

Comment: You could write your `start` script so that it searches the list of names until it finds a name which contains the pattern (`1.2`) for instance at the start of the name. Make sure that you check for ambiguities.

Comment: @user1934428 That was the question, how to combine search with a list.

Comment: You did not say how the list is represented. If the list is in a file (one entry per line), it can be searched with `grep`. If the list is represented as a zsh array, you just loop over the list, and check each entry whether it matches.